# Error when updating LINQ Record in C#

Tags: c#, linq, updates

I'm trying to update a LINQ record in C#, but an error is thrown when `SubmitChanges` is called. I know there is a spelling error in appointment sometimes, but I accidentally coded it that way. The exception/error given is:

> {"Value of member 'Appiontment' of an object of type 'Appointment'
>   changed.\r\nA member defining the identity of the object cannot be
>   changed.\r\nConsider adding a new object with new identity and
>   deleting the existing one instead."}  System.Exception
>   {System.InvalidOperationException}

I am NOT allowed to delete the old record and add a new one. My code is as followz:

```
public bool AppointmentReschedule(string patientFirstName, string patientLastName, string doctorFirstName, string doctorLastName, DateTime newTime)
{
   LINQClassesDataContext dc = new LINQClassesDataContext();

   try
   {
      Appointment a = getAppointment(patientFirstName, patientLastName, doctorFirstName, doctorLastName);
      if (a == null) throw new FaultException("Unable to retrieve appointment data");
      var appointments = dc.Appointments;

      foreach (Appointment b in appointments)
      {
         if (b.Appiontment == a.Appiontment && b.HealthInsuranceNo == a.HealthInsuranceNo && b.MedicalRegistrationNo == a.MedicalRegistrationNo)
         {
            b.Appiontment = newTime;
         }
      }
      dc.SubmitChanges();
   }

   catch (Exception ex)
   {
      throw new FaultException("Unable to update data");
   }
   return true;
}
```

Comment: You don't think it would be helpful to specify the error?

Comment: You do realize that you can do a `find/replace all` on spelling errors don't you...?

Comment: Just updated the question to include the error

Comment: Sorry, but that looks like the worst design ever. `Appointment.Appointment.Appointment`.... What??? Why not use DateTime or Timestamp like normal people? :(

Comment: do you mean Linq to sql?

Comment: @SamIam Linq to SQL is what I am trying to use

Comment: @LewisTherin I know it isn't a good idea. I wasn't thinking while I coded it. I just need to get it working for a university assignment. It's never going to be used in the real world.

Comment: @HaydenO'Sullivan Try to update Appointment fields instead of the whole object? Could work

Comment: @HaydenO'Sullivan: PLEASE don't catch and consume exceptions, if you want to catch and re-throw for break-point purposes then simply `catch (Exception ex) { throw ex; }`. What you're doing right now is wiping out all of the state information necessary to actually debug the issue.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that the `Appiontment` column is part of a primary key in your table.  I would suggest introducing a single primary key into your table, either a `Guid` (`uniqueidentifier` in SQL), which you would add manually during each insert, or an `int`, which you can define as an identity column.